# winpexpect not behaving like pexpect

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko, pexpect

I've been having this problem for days now and I can't figure out whats going wrong.

I have a simple python script using pexpect running on OSX which lauches ssh-keygen and automates hitting return to generate a key pair and it works fine. I want to do the same thing on windows. To get ssh and ssh-keygen on windows, I installed OpenSSH for Windows which lets ssh run from the cmd prompt as a normal windows program using a portion of the CYGWIN support files. I ported the same script to windows and changed pexpect to winpexpect and used the coresponding winspawn to start the subprocess but it stalls out at the first prompt.

```
def generateKeys(self):
    print "GeneratingKeys..."
    gen = winpexpect.winspawn("ssh-keygen -t rsa")
    print gen.expect(":") #This is where it asks for a place to save the keys. retuns 0 if found
    print "before: " + gen.before
    print "after: " + gen.after
    print gen.sendline()
    #Next it should expect a prompt for a passphrase but it never reaches it
    print gen.expect(":")
    print "before: " + gen.before
    print "after: " + gen.after
    print gen.sendline()
```

the output I get is this:

```
GeneratingKeys...
0
before: Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
after: :
2
before: Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
after: :
```

and it's here that it sits for all eternity collecing digital dust bunnies.

I dont understand why its getting ":" after the expected colon either.

Is there perhaps another module I could use that would allow me to communicate better with OpenSSH for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite some time ago, I looked at winpexpect. I couldn't get it to run either, it just hung. Something to do with unsupported sections, and an incomplete port if I remember correctly.

Since I needed it for ssh, I ended up replacing it with [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/). It requires pycrypto, which is a pain to set up on windows, unless you use a [precompiled installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). For the key generation, see [this section of the docs](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html). It has loading and saving of keys. Also pay attention to the missing host key function.

To get up and running quickly, here is an [overview](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/). Please note it does not go over all of the function calls, such as why he is using `AutoAddPolicy()`. Check the docs for the pros/cons and more details.

Comment: I was looking into paramikio, but I wasn't sure if it would work for my project. See, I'm trying to have another application (Unison) use ssh to swap files across the web. Unison looks locally for the ssh client and I'm not sure if it'll use a tunnel created by paramiko.

Comment: @Hiroshi Paramiko can integrate with the local client for keys, see the save function in the docs. I'm not sure about tunnelling, but the unison docs seem to indicate that unison starts ssh itself.

Comment: ^ *facepalm* Sorry, brain fart. I have no idea why I was thinking I need to launch ssh myself. Looking through the save function now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fork project [winpexpect](https://bitbucket.org/weyou/winpexpect): 
This version fixed many bugs. You can have a try.

Comment: Do you know if it fixes the OP's problems?